# Bigquery: Referencing column values with apostrophe in where clause

Tags: string, apostrophe

My where clause is (where Cut_Time_LOS_by_Outgate = "Order's past cutoff") ---> throwing an error because of apostrophe after Order. The open and closed double quotes are part of the whole string.

(where Cut_Time_LOS_by_Outgate = '"Order's past cutoff"')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Column Cut_Time_LOS_by_Outgate  has a list of values and one of the value is "Order's past cutoff". I'm writing a query where I've to filter this column for this value. However because of the apostrophe in Order's, bigquery is throwing an error. How to bypass this error and use Cut_Time_LOS_by_Outgate  =  "Order's past cutoff" as a filter.